# Neo4j - Using Cypher start at a node and Traverse graph to a specified depth and find nodes and relationships

Tags: rest, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a simple graph in which I am trying to start at a particular node and traverse a depth of 2. From this traversal I am trying to extract the names of nodes and relationships.

This is my query,

```
    START n=node(5)
    MATCH p=(n)-[r:Relation*0..2]-(m)
    RETURN n.name,r.name,m.name;
```

I get this error:

```
    Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was Collection<Relationship> (line 3, column 15)
```

In the error description, it points a ^ symbol to r.name

Can Someone help me understand this issue. My goal is to get the names of relationships along way..

From what I have understood, the r is being returned as a collection. Is there a way to display the individual names within the collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sham,

As you noted, the problem is that 'r' is a collection of relationships that may have 0, 1, or 2 elements. You can use the reduce function to create a string of the relationship names and return that string.

```
START n=node(5)
MATCH (n)-[r:Relation*0..2]-(m)
WITH n, m, reduce(s = '', rel IN r | s + rel.name + ',') as rels
RETURN n.name, m.name, rels;
```

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I spent the last few days trying with FOREACH and finally realized it's time to get help from the experts. Sorry I cannot upvote you since my rep points are beginner.

Comment: Let Grace and Peace prevail :)

Comment: @JimBiard I didn't understand this.Can you please elaborate this in more details.
I am also getting the same error and my query is like this.

MATCH (ev1:EV{ev_id:221})-[r1:cousin*]->(vals1:EV) with vals1,r1 
match(vals1)<-[r2:cousin*]-(ev:EV{ev_id:2378}) with vals1, r2  
match(vals1)-[r3:has_product]->(p:Product) 
where r2.filter='f1' and r2.category_id in[70,0] 
return distinct vals1.ev_id as id, vals1.group_id as group_id;

:: What I am doing is that I want all cousin relations of for these ev_ids and when I am applying a filter for that reln Its throwing an error.

Comment: @JugalSingh - It looks like there a number of issues with your query. Without knowing more about what your graph looks like it is hard to know how to respond. The direct answer is that a collection of relationships doesn't behave the same was as a single relationship match. That is why you can't do the WHERE clause that way. I don't think your second and third MATCH clauses accomplish what you are intending. The WHERE clause elements should likely be in your second MATCH clause, among other things.

Comment: @JimBiard  what is nodeID is not a integer to do node (5) if it is a string it gives an error

Comment: @Munaarr - The node(x) function is an old neo4j function that returns a node object when given its numeric node ID. Each element in a neo4j graph has a unique numeric ID. Newer neo4j functions don't use these numeric IDs, and it is good practice to avoid using them if possible. If you know sufficient information about the node you want to start with, you use a MATCH clause instead of START n = node(M). I hope this helps.